# Java If Statement first class or second class

Tags: java, if-statement

I have created this basic code.

It is meant to display a statement that if the parcel is firstclass the cost will be 3.30 else if the parcel is secondclass the cost should be 2.80.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    double cost = 0.00;
    if (this.isFirstClass())
        cost = 3.30;
        str = "First Class Parcel\n";
    else
        cost = 2.80;
        str = "Second Class Parcel\n";
    return str + super.toString() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: surround braces `{ }` for if and else block statements.

Comment: `{...}` adds context and you should be using with multi-line `if` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need braces  ( these symbols -   `{  }`  )if there's 2+ lines in an `if-statement`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    double cost = 0.00;
    if (this.isFirstClass()){
        cost = 3.30;
        str = "First Class Parcel\n";
     }  // ALWAYS USE BRACES !
    else {
        cost = 2.80;
        str = "Second Class Parcel\n"; 
     }
    return str + super.toString() + "\n";
```

If there's just *one* statement after an `if`,  you don't need a brace - however, it is good convention to use it anyway to be readable (and IDE's usually auto-fill for you )

```
if (someBoolVar)
{
   /* I use the brace for readability */
   someOtherVar = 10;
}
```

Comment: Just a niggle, but {} are called braces. Parentheses are the smooth ones: ()

Comment: @Sheeparito - great! anytime'

Comment: @Coffee Another quick question, it now displays this.

First Class Parcel - Cost is £3.3
John Smith, 1 Downing Street, SQ13 9DD
Weight = 1.342kg.

Just need it to display it as '£3.30' not '£3.3'

Comment: @Sheeparito , please make this a sep. question . then I can take a look